# jQuery filter not working

Tags: jquery, filter

Hey i have a event page where different events are displaying, and there i place a filter so that user can select accordingly from those `filters`. Here is the picture how filter look

[image]

As you can see user can select different `days`, `event type` and `drop in must book` `highlights` are not part of `filter`. so i have write a code for it but it not working properly, as there are different days for one event you can see, which creating issue. Here is my code

```
var dropinbook          = jQuery('input[name=droIn]:checked').val();
    var select_days         = jQuery('#select_days').val();
    var select_event_type   = jQuery('#select_event_type').val();


    jQuery('#select_days').change(function(){
        var dropinbook          = jQuery('input[name=droIn]:checked').val();
        var select_days         = jQuery('#select_days').val();
        var select_event_type   = jQuery('#select_event_type').val();
        if(select_days != ''){
            jQuery( ".eventPost" ).css( "display", "none" );
            jQuery( "."+select_days ).css( "display", "block" );
            jQuery( "."+select_event_type ).css( "display", "block" );
            jQuery( "."+dropinbook ).css( "display", "block" );
        }else{
            jQuery( ".eventPost" ).css( "display", "block" );
        }
    });

    jQuery('#select_event_type').change(function(){
        var dropinbook          = jQuery('input[name=droIn]:checked').val();
        var select_days         = jQuery('#select_days').val();
        var select_event_type   = jQuery('#select_event_type').val();
        if(select_event_type != ''){
            jQuery( ".eventPost" ).css( "display", "none" );
            jQuery( "."+select_days ).css( "display", "block" );
            jQuery( "."+select_event_type ).css( "display", "block" );
            jQuery( "."+dropinbook ).css( "display", "block" );
        }else{
            jQuery( ".eventPost" ).css( "display", "block" );
        }
    });


    jQuery(".dropmust").on('change', function(){
        var dropinbook          = jQuery('input[name=droIn]:checked').val();
        var select_days         = jQuery('#select_days').val();
        var select_event_type   = jQuery('#select_event_type').val();

        jQuery( ".eventPost" ).css( "display", "none" );
        jQuery( "."+dropinbook ).css( "display", "block" );
        jQuery( "."+select_days ).css( "display", "block" );
        jQuery( "."+select_event_type ).css( "display", "block" );

    });
```

I know this code is not smart i try my best to find the solution but due to multiple days in one event creating issue. so can some one help me with this. Thanks

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: issue is that when i select day, event type and check box, they must show the events that have all these options. but currently i have multiple days in one event which creating issue

Comment: currently is displaying all event which have full fill the filter requirements like i select drop in, it also show must book as well because in other drop-down i select friday and that event have friday.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfidle to recreate the issue